# PHP AJAX noob question

Tags: php, ajax

Ok so this is likely going to seem like a stupid question. I am trying to accomplish the fairly simple task of having some dynamic content that is generated from a mySQL database via a php file. This works fine, unfortunately when I attempt to add some AJAX functionality to populate another select box based on what is selected it doesn't work. Now I'm sure your thinking let me see the code, but its not needed for the question. Now when I remove the php portion of the page and create a straight html file without anything being populated up front by php the AJAX call works correctly, the problem here is I dont have anything dynamic being generated from the database, so this approach is no good. So here is the question, does AJAX not work if the file is rendered via PHP? Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Forgive me for facetiousness, but let me see the code. There's absolutely no reason why AJAX wouldn't work because the file is rendered dynamically.

Comment: "but its not needed for the question" may I ask why you think it's not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I'm sure your thinking let me see
>   the code, but its not needed for the
>   question.

That's where you are wrong. It would help use provide you with a better answer.

> So here is the question, does AJAX not
>   work if the file is rendered via PHP?

It works no matter your server-side language.

A little example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (isset($_GET['min']) && isset($_GET['max'])) {
    echo rand($_GET['min'],$_GET['max']);
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="randomtext"></p>
        Low:<br /><input type="text" id="min" value="0" /><br />
        High:<br /><input type="text" id="max" value="100" /><br />
        <button id="randomgenerator">Generate random number</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Handler for .ready() called.
                $("#randomgenerator").click(function() {
                    $.get("./",  { "min": $("#min").val(), "max": $("#max").val() }, function(data) {
                        $("#randomtext").html(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was having the darndest time getting it to work but after about 2 hours and a lot of banging my head against my desk it finally gave way. I guess I need to work on my js skillz. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax works if the Javascript syntax is correct.  It's completely independent of the language (html/php/asp/cf/etc.) that the page is rendered with.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is done via Javascript. If removing dynamic content from your page made the AJAX work, then look at what the PHP is spitting out that's breaking the javascript.

Once the generated (or loaded) HTML goes out onto the wire from the server, it's impossible for the browser to tell if it was an actual PHP script, or a static HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute JS that was included via AJAX call, it will not work.  You will have to create a function as a callback and run the callback on AJAX success.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Firebug to keep track of what is the Ajax call returning... take a look at it: http://getfirebug.com/

They are right, BTW, look at you PHP script, there is probably something braking up in there.